# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'update_label'.

Tags: python, kivy

I am stuck with my code, could you please help? After I added on_press to my kv file and describe function update_label, I got error:

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'update_label'.
```

Even if i change description of my function with simple print() function it doesn't works. Thanks in advance!

```
from kivy.app import App    
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout    
from kivy.lang import Builder    
from kivy.uix.button import Button    
from kivy.uix.label import Label    
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout    
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


Builder.load_file('spain2.kv')

class Box2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Box1(StackLayout):
    pass


class Ex42App(App):
    def update_label(self):    
        if self.l1.text == 'amar':    
            self.l2.text = "Translate: to love"    
        else:    
            self.l2.text = "Infinitive not founded"

    def build(self):    
        return Box2()


if __name__=='__main__':

    Ex42App().run()
```

spain2.kv:

```
<Box2>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Box1:
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            id: l1
            text: 'Insert Infinitive'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 30
        TextInput:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 300, 30
        Button:
            text: 'Find'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 30
            on_press: self.update_label

    Label:
        id: l2
        text: 'some data'
        size_hint: None, .9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that he does not know the meaning of `self`, `root` and `app` inside a .kv, for this case consider the following code:

```
<A>:
    property_a: self.a
    property_a1: root.a1
    B:
        property_b: self.b
        property_c1: root.b1
        C:
            property_c: self.c
            property_c1: root.c1
```

As the language .kv is observed, it is declarative and there is a tree of hierarchy.

In this case the `root` refers to the first element: `<A>`.

Instead the `self` refers to an element within the tree, in the case of `self.a` refers to the property `a` belongs to `A`, in the case of `self.c` refers to the property `c` belongs to `C`.

And in the case of app refers refers to the object that belongs to a class that inherits from App, and this object is unique, in your case app refers to the object `Ex42App()` that inherits from Ex42App.

So root and self is relative to a hierarchy tree, for example we can place a more complex structure:

```
<A>:
    B:
        some_property1: self.a # self is B
        some_property2: root.a # root is A

<Y>:
    Z:
        some_property1: self.a # self is Z
        some_property2: root.a # root is Y
```

---

With the above we analyze your case, according to what your code says `update_label` belongs to the `Button` but that is not correct, it belongs to `App` so you must use `app`, on the other hand `update_label` is a function so you must invoke it using `()`.

On the other hand in the code .py point out that `l1` and `l2` belongs to `App` but this does not belong to `App` but to `Box2`, but `l1` and `l2` is only visible inside `Box2`, so that it can be used outside of `Box` you must expose them as properties, and finally `Box2` is the widget that returns `build()` and that element is accessed through `self.root`.

Considering the above, the solution is:

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


Builder.load_file('spain2.kv')

class Box2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Box1(StackLayout):
    pass


class Ex42App(App):
    def update_label(self):
        if self.root.l1.text == 'amar': # <--
            self.root.l2.text = "Translate: to love" # <--
        else:
            self.root.l2.text = "Infinitive not founded" # <--

    def build(self):
        return Box2()


if __name__=='__main__':
    Ex42App().run()
```

***.kv**

```
<Box2>:
    l1: l1 # <--
    l2: l2 # <--
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Box1:
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Label:
            id: l1
            text: 'Insert Infinitive'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 30
        TextInput:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 300, 30
        Button:
            text: 'Find'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 30
            on_press: app.update_label() # <--

    Label:
        id: l2
        text: 'some data'
        size_hint: None, .9
```

Comment: Thank you very much for yours detailed explanation!!! I really didn’t understand difference between self and root!!! Many thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: @ДмитрийПухач If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.